# systemd: fails to run service: error failed to get dbus name

Tags: systemd

My shell script runs fine manually, but causes an error when started by systemd. What is the problem?

I have configured xboxdrv to remap my logitech f310 controller as a mouse on my Raspberry Pi 3B running Buster.

When I run it from the command line as

```
sudo xboxdrv -D -c /usr/share/doc/xboxdrv/logitech.xboxdrv
```

It works fine. So I set it up as a service to run at boot. First I put the above into a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo xboxdrv -D   -c /usr/share/doc/xboxdrv/logitech.xboxdrv --silent  & sleep  1
```

Which I then saved as /usr/share/doc/xboxdrv/logitech.sh and then made executable.

When I run that script with `sudo /usr/share/doc/xboxdrv/logitech.sh` everything works. So far so good.

Then I make a service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=start xboxdrv to configure logitech f310 gamepad
After=default.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/share/doc/xboxdrv/logitech.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I enable this:

```
sudo systemctl enable /etc/sysemd/system/xboxdrv.service
```

and start it:

```
sudo systemctl start xboxdrv.service
```

But now I get an error. This is what I get from journalctl -xe:

```
[ERROR] XboxdrvDaemon::run(): fatal exception: failed to get unique dbus name: 
 Connection ":1.21" is not allowed to own the service "org.seul.Xboxdrv" due to 
 security policies in the configuration file
```

So what does this mean and why am I getting it? I have no idea why xboxdrv needs this connection? What configuration file is it talking about?

And, more to the point, how do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/xboxdrv/xboxdrv/issues/42#issuecomment-155004481) with permissions which can be fixed by [editing or writing a new dbus configuration](https://github.com/xboxdrv/xboxdrv/issues/42#issuecomment-44109839) (which should be the configuration file that is mentioned).

Comment: Thank you! For my purposes I did actually work around it by using sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart